# Modal behavior back/forward button using react-router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, html5-history

I have a React app using React Router 4. A login modal is used to authenticate users. In order to support the UX requirements I've been given, I need to have the back button close the modal.

I was able to accomplish a login modal that supports this using a simple push state:

```
const {history,location} = this.props
const nextState = {showLogin: true}
history.push({...location, state: {...location.state, ...nextState}})
```

The behavior works as expected. HOWEVER… it would be ideal if pressing the forward button did not reopen the modal.

I don't see a way to pop a location off history with react router. But what I'd like to do is listen to route changes and if the location.state changes back to the showLogin modal being falsey, but the location is the same, it pops the previous location off history.

Answer (score 0):

Use `history.replace('')` instead of `history.push('')` while going back.This way, the existing login route, will get replaced from the history stack

Comment: Far as I know it's not possible to block the browsers back button. So I don't see how this is a solution to my problem. That is to say, the user pressed the back button in the browser, nothing happens in code for me to do a replace over a push at the point.